# excel nested if Worksheet

Tags: excel

I want to tell EXCEL to do the following in a cell:

IF there is a number in L3, then use ABS(L3*SQRT((1/D3)+(1/E3))), BU IF L3 is blank AND there is a number in M3, then use ((2*ABS(M3))/SQRT(C3)), FINALLY, IF L3 is blank AND M3 is blank, leave this cell EMPTY

I'm using the following command with no success:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(L3), ABS(L3*SQRT((1/D3)+(1/E3))), IF(AND(ISBLANK(L3), ISNUMBER(M3)), ((2*ABS(M3))/SQRT(C3))), IF(AND(ISBLANK(L3), ISBLANK(M3)),""))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the last IF:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(L3), ABS(L3*SQRT((1/D3)+(1/E3))), IF(AND(L3="", ISNUMBER(M3)), ((2*ABS(M3))/SQRT(C3)), ""))
```

Comment: Scott, thanks, but this that you suggested didn't work!

Comment: When there is a number in M3 it return empty!

Comment: I just edited the answer.  You may need to refresh the screen.